Auroral Kilometric Radiation (AKR) Peak Frequency Calculation
Auroral Kilometric Radiation (AKR) occurs due to emission from charged particles moving in helical paths around planetary magnetic field lines at or around the electron gyro frequency and/or its lower harmonics. Considering the emission from relativistic particles, the emission peaks around a frequency ~ $\gamma^2\nu_c$ where $\gamma$, the Lorentz factor is $\gamma=\large\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(v/c\right)^2}}$ and the cyclotron frequency is $\nu_c=\large\frac{eB}{2\pi m}$.
The average strength of the Earth's magnetic field (which is approximately a dipole) at its surface is $50 \mu T$. It varies from about $25 \mu T$ to $65 \mu T$ over the surface.
How can we determine the frequency of peak emission by electrons moving at one-third the speed of light near the Earth's poles?

I calculated $\gamma$ for an electron moving at one-third the speed of light. After this, I am really not sure what to do with the variation of magnetic field.
